# Como agrego un evento onClick individual para cada botón? (Uso RecyclerView)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy usando un "FloatingActionButton". A continuación adjunto algunas imagenes para explicar mas a detalle. [Click Aquí para ver la Imágen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhRGz.png)

Estoy utilizando RecylerView, implementé un boton flotante que este mismo se repite en todos los Items, Pero al darle funcion, Ejemplo: un Intent. Este se repite en los demás. No quiero eso; quiero que sea evento individual.

**MAINACTIVITY.JAVA**

```
private final String JSON_URL = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/albeiro3/dc78fb430420f2cccea6ebd5b2679946/raw/1bb2cd18c3ad4bad5ff7249e6a82c0794f5804aa/anime.json" ;
private JsonArrayRequest request ;
private RequestQueue requestQueue ;
private List<Anime> lstAnime ;
private RecyclerView recyclerView ;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lstAnime = new ArrayList<>() ;
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewid);
    jsonrequest();

}

private void jsonrequest() {

    request = new JsonArrayRequest(JSON_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            JSONObject jsonObject  = null ;

            for (int i = 0 ; i < response.length(); i++ ) {
                try {
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i) ;
                    Anime anime = new Anime() ;
                    anime.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    anime.setDescription(jsonObject.getString("description"));
                    anime.setRating(jsonObject.getString("Rating"));
                    anime.setCategorie(jsonObject.getString("categorie"));
                    anime.setNb_episode(jsonObject.getInt("episode"));
                    anime.setStudio(jsonObject.getString("studio"));
                    anime.setImage_url(jsonObject.getString("img"));
                    anime.setSms(jsonObject.getString("sms"));
                    anime.setSms(jsonObject.getString("sms"));
                    lstAnime.add(anime);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            setuprecyclerview(lstAnime);


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    requestQueue.add(request);
}

private void setuprecyclerview(List<Anime> lstAnime) {
    RecyclerViewAdapter myadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,lstAnime) ;
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myadapter);

   }
}
```

**PELICULASACTIVITY.JAVA**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_anime);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "PRUEBA", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });





    getSupportActionBar().hide();



    String name  = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_name");
    String description = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_description");
    String studio = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_studio") ;
    String category = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_category");
    int nb_episode = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("anime_nb_episode") ;
    String rating = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_rating") ;
    String image_url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_img") ;
    String sms = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_sms") ;


    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = findViewById(R.id.collapsingtoolbar_id);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(true);

    TextView tv_name = findViewById(R.id.aa_anime_name);
    TextView tv_studio = findViewById(R.id.aa_studio);
    TextView tv_categorie = findViewById(R.id.aa_categorie) ;
    TextView tv_description = findViewById(R.id.aa_description);
    TextView tv_rating  = findViewById(R.id.aa_rating);
    ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.aa_thumbnail);
    Button Sms = findViewById(R.id.aa_sms);



    tv_name.setText(name);
    tv_categorie.setText(category);
    tv_description.setText(description);
    tv_rating.setText(rating);
    tv_studio.setText(studio);
    Sms.setOnClickListener(this);

    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(name);


    RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions().centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.loading_shape).error(R.drawable.loading_shape);



    Glide.with(this).load(image_url).apply(requestOptions).into(img);


}
}
```

**ACTIVITY_MAIN.XML**

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.demotxt.myapp.myapplication.activities.MainActivity"
android:background="#303030">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerviewid"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

**ANIME_ROW_ACTIVITY.XML**

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:padding="8dp"
android:background="@drawable/bgg"
android:id="@+id/container">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/loading_shape"
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">


    <TextView
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/anime_name"
        android:text="Anime Title"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Category"
        android:id="@+id/categorie"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rating"
        android:text="0.0"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rating_background"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_star_black_24dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"/>
    <Button
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SMS"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/aa_sms"/>
    <TextView
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Studio"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/studio"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

En **ANIME_ACTIVITY.JAVA** le coloque al boton flotante un "*Snackbar.make*" para hacer una prueba y este se repite en todos. Si alguna cosa me falta, Favor me ayudarías!!! Gracias.
[Click Aquí para ver la imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh8mO.png)

**NOTA:** *Soy Principiante, Tengo Poco conocimiento estoy aprendiendo un poco de programación, espero me entiendan, gracias*

Comment: Hola! Una consulta, el problema que tienes es que cuando presionas en el floating button aparece el snack-bar, cierto? Si es así, a que te refieres cuando dices "en todos los lados". Entiendo que el floating button esta en activity_peliculas.xml

Comment: @rguzman Aparece el Snack-bar Normal, lo que se quiere lograr es que el mensaje (Snack-bar) no se repita en los demás Items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen dia @Albeiro J. Entiendo mas o menos lo que quieres hacer. Intenta hacer esto.

```
FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String animeName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_name");
            String url = "";
            switch (animeName) {
                case "Película 1":
                    url = "https://www.example.com/pleícula_1.html";
                    break;
                case "Película 2":
                    url = "https://www.example.com/pleícula_2.html";
                    break;
                case "Película 3":
                    url = "https://www.example.com/pleícula_3.html";
                    break;
                case "Película 4":
                    url = "https://www.example.com/pleícula_4.html";
                    break;
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VideoPlayer.class);
            intent.putExtra("url_movie", url);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Puedes crear una nueva actividad llamada VideoPLayer e implementar un Video View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.infinityapp.stackoverflow.VideoPlayer">

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Luego en el método onCreate() recuperas la url y se lo pasas al VideoView

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class VideoPlayer extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);

        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(getIntent().getExtras().getString("url_movie")));
        videoView.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, voy a implementarlo.

Comment: Si quiero implementar un Intent como sería? Claro, que no se repita el mismo intent

Comment: Como sería implementar un intent. Quieres lanzar una actividad para cada película, o quizás quieres ir a una URL, lanzar intent de compartir, hay varias formas de implementar intent. Cuéntame lo que quieres hacer y así puedo ayudarte.

Comment: Quiero ir a una URL utilizando un VideoPlayer para cada pelicula.

Comment: Es decir que quieres reproducir la película utilizando una URL?

Comment: Asi es, es lo que necesito.

Comment: Me Podrías ayudar por fa!!

Comment: Ok, te ayudo. Voy a editar mi respuesta, no lo he probado aun porque mi conexión a Internet no es muy buena, pero debería funcionar

Comment: Ya edité la respuesta. Si quieres tener un código mas limpio a la hora de recuperar la url puedes agregar un extra cuando lanzas PelículasActivity (supongo que debes tener las urls organizadas ya para cada película) y sólo tienes que obtener ese extra y se lo pasas a la actividad VideoPlayer cuando la inicies, y te evitas tener que implementar un switch y tener código ambiguo. Si tienes dudas ya sabes. Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: No olvides añadir el permiso de Internet en el Manifest.